# Deriving formula for approximating the derivative

Tags: calculus

I am trying to figure out how $f'(x) \approx \frac{1}{12h} \left [-f(x+2h) + 8f(x+h)-8f(x-h)+f(x-2h) \right ]$. with $O(h^4)$error

I've tried simplifying $f(x+2h) - f(x-2h)$ (from the respective taylor expansions), but I do not get the result above. Is there something else that must be done?

Comment: Why don't you consider the two middle terms?  The combination of each term is not coincidence.

Comment: hint: use $f(x+a)\approx f(a)+f'(x)a$.

Comment: Ah, f(x+h) and f(x-h). Got it